# How can I tweak this regex for detecting correct date format in my dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, dataframe

if I had this dataframe:

```
df:
name  dob
will  05-2020
John  4-2020
James 07-1999
Rob   2-2001
kim   1-20202020
Jane  112-2020
```

I Want to detect dates(mm-yyyy) in the dob column under the conditions:

1. The year can't be longer than 4 characters (must be int of course)
2. the month can be one digit or two (examples: 02, 2, 12, 11, 10, 9, 09: are all acceptable) but if its two digits the first character can only be from 0-1 and the 2nd 0-9

I have this regex so far:

```
r'\d{2}[-/]\d{4}'
```

but Im not getting the resulta I want. under my conditions I shouldn't detect kim or jane in my dataframe.

any ideas?

Comment: `[0-1]?\d[-\/]\d{4}` is it ok

Comment: Please check the answers below. If none helps you please provide feedback, else, consider accepting the answer that worked for you.

Comment: Since you have a `dataframe` tag, I think [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61560050/3832970) with a Pandas approach will be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using custom *digit* boundaries (`(?<!\d)` lookbehind and `(?!\d)` lookahead) to make sure you only match numbers of your choice and make sure you are matching *years*, not just 4-digit numbers like `9873` with `(?:19|20)\d{2}` non-capturing group with an alternation operator + any two digits. Days can be matched as in [Jan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61555186/3832970), with `(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])` pattern.

After extracting the dates with `str.extract`, you may cast them to date time with `pd.to_datetime`.

With `.fillna()`, you may manipulate no match entries (I kept them empty in the code below).

The regex is

```
(?<!\d)((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:19|20)\d{2})(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ulmxx4/1). Details:

- `(?<!\d)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is a digit
- `((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:19|20)\d{2})` - Capturing group 1 (required for `str.extract`):

  - `(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])` - an optional `0` and a digit from `1` to `9`, or `1` and then `0`, `1` or 2`(so, numbers from`1`to`12`)
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `(?:19|20)\d{2}` - `19` or `20` and then any 2 digits
- `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is a digit.

Full snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
data = { 'dob': ['will\t05-2020', 'John\t4-2020', 'James\t07-1999', 'Rob\t2-2001','kim\t1-20202020','Jane\t112-2020']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = df['dob'].str.extract(r'(?<!\d)((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:19|20)\d{2})(?!\d)').fillna("")
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m%Y', errors='ignore')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
               dob     Date
0    will\t05-2020  05-2020
1     John\t4-2020   4-2020
2   James\t07-1999  07-1999
3      Rob\t2-2001   2-2001
4  kim\t1-20202020         
5   Jane\t112-2020
```

Comment: this is perfect! I am practicing these expressions so I have a question to ask: If I wanted another regex without the optional 0 would I just remove the '?:0?' portion?

Comment: @JTHDR If you do not allow an optional `0`, yes, just remove `0?`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
\b(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{4}\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ZQcwX5/2/).

---

Note, as this is a frequent question, there's a [**module called `datefinder`**](https://pypi.org/project/datefinder/) which you could use:

```
import datefinder
matches = datefinder.find_dates(string_with_dates)
```

Internally, it uses regular expressions as well, if you want to see the code, [**see their github repo**](https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder/blob/master/datefinder/constants.py).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex: `\b(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[-/]\d{4}\b`

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DqnIiq/26) here